# Unwanted octothorpe character (#) added to request cycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm using the [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/) gem to sign in users with Google.

After the oauth response is handled in controller, the user is redirected to another page: `/dashboard`. When landing on this page - a octothorpe (aka a [hash/number/pound](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octothorpe)) character is added to the URL:

```
https://myapp.tld/dashboard#
```

From what it seems, that pound sign is somehow coming with the oauth response. But I cannot gather how and why it consequently gets passed on to the final page.

Any clues how this happens OR otherwise how to clear a redirect from passing that character?

Comment: What do you mean by pound sign? Actual pound sign is £ .

Comment: Do you know the correct name for this character `#` ?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octothorpe

Comment: Or the Hash symbol, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-is-the-name-of-the-symbol

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your response type is set to code in the URL you are providing the user.

```
response_type=code
```